# Performing operations and inserting into list in Python

Tags: python, list

So I am trying to perform the following operation on a List in Python.

```
p = []
p.append(1)
K=4
en=0.0
lambda1=0.8
mu1=1

for i in range (1, K+1):
 p[i] = p[i-1] * (lambda1 / mu1) 
 en += (i * p[i])           
 prob_arrival += p[i-1] * lambda1
```

I understand where I am going wrong. Basically I need to cumulatively populate the list. Right now I am getting an error as IndexError: list assignment index out of range.
How do I fix this?

Comment: What are you doing with `prob_arrival` ?

Comment: I am using that value in a later part of the program. Right now I am unable to populate the "p" list itself

Comment: So where are you going wrong?

Comment: p[i] = p[i-1] * (lambda1 / mu1)

This is causing this error:
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a list with only 1 element as `p[i]` and `p[i-1]`  with `i` as `1` , without actually inserting any values into that position. This would cause the `IndexError` you are seeing. You should append values to your list in your `for` loop. You can access the last row in the list using `-1` index. Example -

```
p = [1]
K=4
en=0.0
lambda1=0.8
mu1=1
prob_arrival = 0 #Or some other default value
for _ in range (0, K):
    p.append(p[-1] * (lambda1 / mu1))
    en += (i * p[-1])
    prob_arrival += p[-2] * lambda1
```

I also simplified `p = []; p.append(1)` to `p=[1]` .

Answer (score 0):

You are going wrong with your for loop. Python lists begin at 0, and end at len(yourArray) - 1. I think you meant to type

```
for x in range(0,K):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: for x in range(0,K) would mean that I iterate over the 1st element to the penultimate element (basically upto K-1)

Comment: No. range(x,y) means x, x+1, x+2, x+3...y-1; not x, x+1, x+2, x+3...y. That means it would iterate from the 1st to the last element.